# GCM for sending notifications on android mobile app from Salesforce

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

We are trying to send the notification to an Android App about any event generated in salesfoece(Like creating an account), using the Google's GCM(Google Cloud Messaging).
Here is the link that tell about the GCM ,

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#android-app

I m using Eclipse for creating Android App and my GCM server gave me the SenderID and API key.

But the problem is , How can I use Salesforce as my 3rd Party Application,from where the notifications are generated.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the Spring 14 release, Salesforce supports Google ( GCM ) and Apple ( APNS ) mobile push notifications via the Connected Apps framework. Please check the Mobile Push Notifications Tip Sheet on Developer Force for more information: http://www2.developerforce.com/en/mobile/resources

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to monitor the API for events from salesforce by polling; otherwise you might be able to get events sent to a specific URL.  I'm not positive that you can specifically send a push notification from salesforce itself.

However, with your application you should be able to build in some middleware to handle that.